# Resource for learning TDD with asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tdd

Is it possible to do TDD on asp.net MVC 3? And if so, what are some good online resources? As far as I know, MVC 3 is the latest version that is out. But most of the tdd articles I google are for MVC 1. Even the only two books I've been able to find on TDDing in MVC are both for 1.0

[Asp.net MVC Test Driven Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470447621)

[Test Drive asp.net MVC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356530)

Even on the official Microsoft website the article that's an [MVC TDD walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416511%28VS.98%29.aspx) is for MVC 2.0.

It's starting to make me think TDD is just not practical on asp.net MVC or that it's not heavily supported.

Comment: "It's starting to make me think TDD is just not practical on asp.net MVC or that it's not heavily supported" is completely wrong

Comment: TDD is a way of developing software, and has not much to do with the technology you choose (although some technologies -such as MVC- make it much easier to unit test your code). Besides, when you are able to write an MVC1 app using TDD, why do you think you can't do the same with MVC3?

Comment: @Mark I'd love to be proven wrong. Just point me to some CURRENT and UP TO DATE resources to learn how to TDD on asp.net mvc. I'm TRYING to and can't find anything. You say I'm "completely wrong" and yet don't give me any proof.

Comment: TDD is an approach to build rock-solid apps with creating tests before the actual implementation.

Comment: Steven Sanderson covers TDD in all editions of his MVC related books including [Pro ASP.Net MVC3](http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-3-Framework/dp/1430234040/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1340133168&sr=8-1&keywords=Pro+ASP.Net+MVC3) and I highly recommend it to anyone who is doing ASP.Net MVC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the best resource I know for learning TDD:

[Roy Osherove - The Art of Unit Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988274)

After reading this and reading the following MVC3 book:

[Sanderson and Freeman - Pro ASP.NET MVC3 Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005CHD6MU)

With this you will know enough to get started with Test Driven Development in MVC3.

Answer (score 2):

Most concepts of TDD are fairly generic so TDD resources for C#-programming in general should get you a long way.

For a MVC-solution to play around with you can have a look at https://github.com/tekpub/mvc3 (I recommend the videos too but they are not for free).

Brad Wilson has a lot of goodies about testing and MVC (http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/testing-routing-and-url-generation-in-aspnet-mvc.html for example).

[This video](http://www.vimeo.com/24536954) is more about architecture of an application but he does some testing too.

Comment: I understand how certain aspects are generic. But testing on the MVC side will involve things like controllers, models, etc. Or maybe it's that asp.net MVC doesn't really support anything more than pure unit tests? I'm coming from rails where they have tests for controller, models, views, routes, everything. And TDDing rails can be quite different from TDDing a pure ruby app. I was assuming it would be similar in .net MVC

Comment: Controllers are easy to test, routes are a bit messier because they require some stubs and setup code. Models typically aren't a problem because they really have no dependency on the MVC framework itself. I'd also say TDD of the V and C in MVC doesn't really get you far since the design is already baked. TDD of the model and the business layer might reveal more.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the following resources are not posted yet.
[TDD with ASP.NET MVC 3, Moq and Dependency Injection](http://danielglyde.blogspot.com/2011/07/tdd-with-aspnet-mvc-3-moq-and.html)  and nice discussion in stackoverflow on this topic [TDD and Test Data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4771697/1437962)

Answer (score 0):

Testability was a goal from the beginning. I suspect one the reasons you don't see "TDD with MVC 3" as a dedicated topic is because the techniques haven't changed since v1.0. I cover unit testing controller actions with nUnit in the introductory video of my [MVC 3 course](http://www.asp.net/mvc/pluralsight) on the asp.net site.

Comment: Thanks for the response K. Scott Allen! Explains exactly why I was confused. Side note - big fan of your blog but have been out of the .net scene for a few years.